# Universal Docking Station

Tags: laptop, hdmi, docking-stations

I am a software developer that is once in a while working from home and of course I dont want to have double the peripherals on my desk so I use a kvm switch.

Now my company doesn't want to buy a docking station for me so after a long time of endurement I decided to buy a docking station myself.

First I was thinking of buying one of these [Docking Stations from HP](https://www.hp.com/de-de/shop/list.aspx?sel=ACC&ctrl=f&fc_ptyp_workspace=1&source=bing&channel=cpc&adcampaign=OLS-DE-Bra-PHR-Bing-SEM-Baseline-Zubeh%C3%B6r&addisttype=s&kw=hp%20docking%20station&adid=83356935019615&gclid=1c3155f6ef0017b08def317c1f2fb3de&gclsrc=3p.ds&msclkid=1c3155f6ef0017b08def317c1f2fb3de) but then I thought I don't want to be depending. In case I might have a different laptop in one or two years...

**TLDR:
Anyone can recommend a thunderbolt (my work-laptop is a hp) compatible generic docking station that is universal and would allow other OEM fabricated laptops as well? It should have at least 2 HDMI-connections and some USB-3 would be nice as well. Anyone has good experiences there?**

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has Thunderbolt ports on it, you should get the newest Thunderbolt 4 docking station for your laptop.  Most of TB4 docking stations currently in the market are all using the same Intel's Thunderbolt dock frameworks to make the product designs.  So, basically, there are multi TB4 downstream ports and USB 3.x type A port(s) on it.

My own suggestion will be the OWC TB hub, which currently is under promotion for only around USD$129/each.